# help with SAT writing section

Tags: grammar

> Scientists have long believed that caels originated in North America and then spread throughout the world, **a theory that was first proposed** after a camel fossil was discovered in Canada's Yukon Territory in 1913. 
>   **A) No Change**
>   **B) this first being proposed**
>   **C) this theory was first proposed**
>   **D) and the first theory proposed**

I had thought the answer would be B), rather than A) although A) too sounds correct. However, the answer apparently is indeed A). However, I don't understand why I should choose A) over B)... Could someone help me understand this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion B) would read as:

> Scientists have long believed that camels originated in North America and then spread throughout the world, **this first being proposed** after a camel fossil was discovered in Canada's Yukon Territory in 1913.

In the sentence it is unclear to what **this** refers. Also **this first being** could refer to the camel or to a scientist (a **being** is a **creature**).

But in the given sentence it is clear that the origin of camels is a theory, and why the theory came about.